# Linear invariants under unitary transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

What linear functions of elements of square matrices are invariant under unitary similarity transformations? For example, $tr(UMU^\dagger) = tr(M)$ for any $M$ and unitary $U$. $tr(M^\dagger)$ also works as do multiples of these. Are there any others? If not, is there an elementary proof?

For the quadratic case $tr(MM)$, $tr(MM^\dagger)$, etc. also work but I am specifically interested in a proof for the linear case.

This question arises when justifying the relationship between density matrices in composite quantum systems.

Comment: When you say "invariant under unitary transformations", presumably you mean under unitary *changes of basis* or unitary *conjugation*

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: @cdude or perhaps "unitary *similarity*"

Comment: @cdude So again, the term "unitary transformation" is not standard in this context, but at least it's clear what you mean. In any case, as the other comment seems to be getting at, your question will be closed unless you edit it to provide an indication that you've attempted to answer the question on your own.

Comment: Well, I gave two examples. I'm not sure what more I can do.

Comment: @cdude As a hint towards a proof, begin by noting that every real-linear function $f:\Bbb C^{n\times n} \to \Bbb C$ can be written in the form $M \mapsto \operatorname{tr}(AM)$ or $M \mapsto \operatorname{tr}(AM^*)$ for some matrix $A$. Use invariance under unitary similarity to conclude that $AM = MA$ must hold for all matrices $M$.

Comment: @cdude At the very least it would help if you edited to say what inspired you to ask the question in the first place, and maybe if you said something about similarity-invariant functions that aren't necessarily linear. See the links in the other comment as well as [this one](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: @cdude I think those changes will be sufficient. I'll leave an answer later if I find the time. In the meantime, my earlier comment is an outline of the proof that I had in mind

Comment: Although you are limiting to linear functions, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specht%27s_theorem may be of interest in a more general setting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you allow $\text{tr}(M^{\dagger})$ I assume you mean linear over $\mathbb{R}$. In that case you've found all examples. This boils down to a straightforward argument in representation theory: you are asking for a classification of morphisms $M_n(\mathbb{C}) \to \mathbb{R}$ of $U(n)$-representations, where $U(n)$ acts on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ by conjugation and acts on $\mathbb{R}$ trivially.

Since $U(n)$ is compact, its finite-dimensional representations are completely reducible, so $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ decomposes into a direct sum of irreducible representations, and it suffices to compute the part of this direct sum consisting of trivial representations, or equivalently the subspace of invariants. Equivalently, it suffices to compute the subspace of matrices $Z \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $UZU^{-1} = Z$ for all $U \in U(n)$.

This is equivalent to computing the space of endomorphisms of $\mathbb{C}^n$ as a complex representation of $U(n)$, and since this representation is irreducible, by [Schur's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_lemma) its endomorphism ring is $\mathbb{C}$, the scalar multiples of the identity. So $Z = \lambda I$ must be a scalar multiple of the identity.

This means that the real dimension of the space of invariants is $2$, and since $\text{tr}(M)$ and $\text{tr}(M^{\dagger})$ are linearly independent they must be a basis of the space of invariant linear functionals.